# using lodash get in react componentWillReceiveProps won't work

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this piece of code

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.ad !== this.props.ad) {
    this.setState({
      body: nextProps.ad && nextProps.ad.submission && nextProps.ad.submission.content
    })
  }
}
```

somehow I have to check every level of object, can't use lodash's _.get, I tried `_.get(nextProps.ad.submission.content)`, no error found but my this.state.body is `undefined`, does it have to do with `componentWillReceiveProps`?

Answer (score 0):

- You should avoid updating the state unless you are sure the data is defined.
- Avoid using if(nextProps !== this.props) as this is often an indication you should be managing this data in the parent element.

The issue is most likely due to the face that nextProps.ad.submission.content is not defined, you need to put in checks to make sure that the data exists. Here is a small example how to do this better:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.ad !== this.props.ad) {
        if(nextProps.ad && nextProps.ad.submission && nextProps.ad.submission.content) {
            this.setState({
                body: nextProps.ad.submission.content
            })
        } else {
            // throw error as content is undefined
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what not `if(nextProps.ad && nextProps.ad.submission && nextProps.ad.submission.content) {` is the `!!` really needed?

Comment: you are right this is not needed, this has however brought up another use case to watch out for, if  `nextProps.ad.submission.content == 0` this would return false.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is:

```
_.get(nextProps.ad.submission.content)
```

and the way to use the `_.get` function to achieve what you want is like this:

```
_.get(nextProps, 'ad.submission.content')
```

See the documentation [here: lodash _.get](https://lodash.com/docs#get)